# FindNextFile(...) dont "see" files WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, directory

My question is: why my output is given me the "recycle.bin" file, and that's all nothing else, like it wouldn't be any files in there ("C:\*" / "D:\*")
after i call FindNextFile() i get error 18 (no more files in directory), the problem is, that it's wrong

```
bool data_confersion(PWIN32_FIND_DATAW pFileData, P_SINGLE_FILE pFile){

    //file sieze determining 
    pFile->filesize = pFileData->nFileSizeLow;
    ((int*)&pFile->filesize)[1] = pFileData->nFileSizeHigh;

    pFile->attributes = pFileData->dwFileAttributes;
    pFile->name = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH];
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_PATH; i++){
        pFile->name[i] = pFileData->cFileName[i];
    }


    if(FileTimeToSystemTime(&pFileData->ftCreationTime, &pFile->CreationTime) ||
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&pFileData->ftLastAccessTime, &pFile->LastAccessTime) ||
        FileTimeToSystemTime(&pFileData->ftLastWriteTime, &pFile->LastWriteTime))
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool FILESYSTEM::updateFolderContent(P_DRIVE _d){
    LPTSTR t = new wchar_t[128];
    int i=0;
    P_SINGLE_FILE p_t_file;
    bool b_found = false;
    int i_filesCount = 0;

    for(; _d->logicalDrives[i]!=L'\0'; i++)
        t[i]=_d->logicalDrives[i];
    t[i]=L'*';
    t[i+1]=0;
    LPVOID v;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW p;
    Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&v);
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(t, &p);



    //SCANING FOR NEXT FILES
    do{
        //LOOP CHECKING IF FILE IS SAVED IN DATA BASE
        i_filesCount++;
        for(int i=0; i<_d->content.size; i++){
            p_t_file = _d->content[i];
            for(int j=0; p_t_file->name[i]!=0; i++){
                if(p_t_file->name[i]!=p.cFileName[i])
                    b_found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!b_found){
            p_t_file = new SINGLE_FILE;
            _d->content.push(p_t_file);
            data_confersion(&p , p_t_file);
        }
        b_found = false;
    }while(FindNextFile(hFind, &p));

    int err = GetLastError();
if(!FindClose(hFind)){
    err = GetLastError();
}

    if(i_filesCount < _d->content.size){
        for(int i=0; i<_d->content.size; i++){
            p_t_file = _d->content[i];
            if(INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == GetFileAttributes(p_t_file->name)){
                int err = GetLastError();
                _d->content.pop(i);
                i--;
            }           
        }

    }

    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(v);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, there used to be a comment here that pointed you to the solution, but it seems to have been deleted.  I don't know why.  As I recall, it involved using one of the Shell functions rather than `FindNextFile`.

Comment: This is quite bad code. Unnecessary memory allocations which subsequently leak, `strcpy` written out manually, suspicious cast, misspelled function names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `t` string is most likely wrong. It's basically `logicalDrives` (plural) with a single `*` appended. That's rather unlikely to be correct.